# How to manage deployment in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I have published 3 versions of Lambda function with aliases - DEV, TEST and PROD
the ARN is like this -

> arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:37598198XXXX:function:functionName:DEV

where DEV points to `$Latest` version and TEST to `version 1` and PROD to `version 2`.
It works fine for DEV whenever I deploy new updates (to $Latest). However to deploy to PROD or TEST I have to first create a new version (say 3) and then delete the alias (say TEST) and then set version(3) with alias (TEST).

> Is there a way so that I can choose which version DEV/PROD points to
>   without deleting and creating aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change what version a Lambda alias points to easily via the AWS CLI.

For example:

```
aws lambda update-alias \
--region region \
--function-name helloworld \
--function-version 2 \
--name BETA
```